# could not convert string to float - float DF with no spaces

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, type-conversion, data-science

I have one error from my sklearn MinMaxScaler process: could not convert string to float
But all my Data Frame is float with no empty spaces:

```
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   Data         124 non-null    datetime64[ns] - THIS ONE I EXCLUDED
 1   p1           124 non-null    float64       
 2   p2           124 non-null    float64       
 3   p3           124 non-null    float64       
 4   p4           124 non-null    float64       
 5   p5           124 non-null    float64       
 6   p6           124 non-null    float64       
 7   p7           124 non-null    float64       
 8   p8           124 non-null    float64       
 9   p9           124 non-null    float64


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=df.drop('p0',axis=1).values

X=df.drop('p9',axis=1).values

y=df['p9'].values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler=MinMaxScaler()

X_train=scaler.fit_transform('X_train')
```

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'X_train'**

Can anyone give to me an idea where the problem is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you print(X)? Let's see what is coming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line:

```
X_train=scaler.fit_transform('X_train')
```

should be

```
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```